# Why are lubicants like grease or oil slippery?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I know that grease or oil are slippery in nature but never thought of why? I want to know what causes this tendency.

Comment: Aside from the tautology (lubricants need to be slippery to be lubricants), this might be better suited at [chemistry](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com).

Comment: [Here's](http://www.petroleum.co.uk/oil-as-a-lubricant) a pretty simple explanation that seems to make sense to me.  If you're interested in a more detailed intro, I'd look for lecture notes on Tribology (Likely under Mech. Eng. or Materials Science).

Answer (score 1):

1) They are non-polar, which means that it does not have positive and negative ends and consequently do not attract each other.

2) Also the viscosity of these fluids is less and hence have low resistance to flow. Therefore, they are slippery

Comment: Many lubricants have quite a high viscosity.  Compare grease or engine oil with water.

Comment: Ice and water are polar, yet they are slippery.